# Как преобразовать один массив в другой (изменение структуры массива)?

Tags: php, массивы

Как преобразовать вот такой массив (var_dump):

```
array(263) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    '@attributes' =>
    array(2) {
      'gv_id' =>
      string(2) "98"
      'gv_Name' =>
      string(30) "Dell"
    }
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    '@attributes' =>
    array(2) {
      'gv_id' =>
      string(2) "26"
      'gv_Name' =>
      string(4) "ASUS"
    }
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    '@attributes' =>
    array(2) {
      'gv_id' =>
      string(2) "10"
      'gv_Name' =>
      string(2) "HP"
    }
  }
  [3] =>
  array(1) {
    '@attributes' =>
    array(2) {
      'gv_id' =>
      string(2) "12"
      'gv_Name' =>
      string(5) "Intel"
    }
  }
}
```

к такому виду (var_dump):

```
array(263) {
  [98] =>
  string(30) "Dell"
  [26] =>
  string(4) "ASUS"
  [10] =>
  string(2) "HP"
  [12] =>
  string(5) "Intel"
}
```

foreach не предлагать пожалуйста, желательно с использованием функций для работы с массивами, но без callback-функций. Везде ключи и значения - string. Такое вообще возможно?

Comment: А чем вам foreach из одного оператора не нравится?

Comment: *foreach не предлагать пожалуйста, желательно с использованием функций для работы с массивами, но без callback-функций.* - вам шашечки или ехать?

Comment: а array_column ?

Comment: Почему такие странные ограничения?

Comment: @A1essandro, да это вероятно учебное задание. Вопрос вообще закрыть надо в таком случае.

Comment: Я так понимаю ограничения из-за скорости работы. Callback-функция - самое медленное решение, потом foreach, а встроенные функции - самые быстрые. Единственный вариант - array_column, но с оговорками

Comment: @NikitaRomannikov, два вложенных `array_column`, по вашему будут работать быстрее чем один `foreach`? Что-то я в этом сильно сомневаюсь

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev вот поэтому и с оговорками) Плюс там 5.5 еще нужен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для подобных задач в PHP есть функция [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php). Пример ее использования:

```
$src = array(
    array(
        '@attributes' => array(
            'gv_id' => 98,
            'gv_Name' => 'Dell',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        '@attributes' => array(
            'gv_id' => 12,
            'gv_Name' => 'Intell',
        ),
    ),
);

$res = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['@attributes']['gv_Name'];
}, $src);

var_dump($res);
```

**UPD:** Пример выше не позволяет задавать произвольные ключи элементам массива. А классическое решение с `foreach` позволяет, хотя и является более громоздким:

```
$res = array();
foreach ($src as $key => $value) {
    $res[$item['@attributes']['gv_id']] = $item['@attributes']['gv_Name'];
}

var_dump($res);
```

Comment: Автор написал "callback не предлагать". Хотя странные ограничения...

Comment: @A1essandro, автор внес это дополнение _после_ того, как я подготовил ответ :) Как бы то ни было, мое решение вполне рабочее, если оно не устраивает автора, возможно кто-то даст ответ лучше.

Comment: Спасибо, видимо array_map с callback самое быстрое и короткое решение.

Comment: @Avtandil, короткое -- да. По скорости -- нужно проводить тесты. Есть у меня такое чувство, что `foreach` может быть быстрее.

Comment: да по длине, надо заметить ... `foreach ($arr as $item)
     $new[$item['@attributes']['gv_id']] = $item['@attributes']['gv_Name'];`

Comment: @Avtandil не факт, что самое быстрое и по памяти то же не факт. Обычный цикл с одним действием может быть быстрее

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, а где в вашем примере `gv_id` в ключах выходного массива?

Comment: @korytoff, вы правы, упустил этот момент.

Comment: @Avtandil С callback это самое медленное решение. Самое быстрое - с for или while, даже не с foreach

Comment: @korytoff, обновил ответ